# How to set the source rate to zero after 10 PM in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model, where I need to turn the source of customers to 0 after 10 PM. That means, no customer will be generated after 10 PM.

Answer (score 0):

to turn the source rate to zero you do this:

```
source.set_rate(0);
```

To do that after 10pm, you can use an event that triggers every day at 10pm
[image: event]

Comment: Thanks. But the issue with using event is, the whole system hangs after event is triggered.

I have agents in my system that are stuck and dont sink.

Comment: you can create another event to get the source rate back to normal..  you didn't specify anything on your question

Comment: I used double infinity and it worked. Thanks!